# Jetpack Compose: add multiple screens to the back stack on init with a normal animation

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack-navigation

I have a regular `NavGraphBuilder` with a regular calls for `navigation` with a simple side slide animation. In a regular scenario it works fine: adds screens to the back stack with an expected animation.

But for some scenarios I need to add multiple screens to the back stack on the application start. So, if I call `NavController.navigate...` multiple times on init, animation is broken: instead of slide animation the last screen animates from the top-left corner on from opposite direction at all (depending on device or Android version). If I add a delay between each `NavController.navigate...` call - animation works fine.

I'd like to show the last screen with normal animation and a required back stack. Maybe, somebody faced this and find a solution?